# Trouble Installing Git on CentOS

Tags: linux, git, centos, yum

I'm having trouble installing Git on CentOS 5.5 x86_64. I'm not an expert at this type of thing, what's the problem?

```
root@server [/]# yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates-testing: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Figured it out, it was because of cpanel.

This fixes it:

```
yum install git --disableexcludes=main
```

Comment: Thanks, this workaround worked nicely and on a server which didn't have cpanel installed, but was still set to exclude perl in /etc/yum.conf.

Comment: Will this end up changing/overwriting the perl version that cPanel installed and will that be a potentials source of issues?